# What does it mean the phrase in this song?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean the phrase "phantom doors swing"in the song Switch Lanes by Tyga feat The Game?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do lyrics interpretation here, and OP's cited text has no immediately obvious, or widely-understood meaning to Anglophones in general

Comment: I think we can give literal meanings and leave it that.

Answer (score 3):

A phantom {something} is one that is not really present.  It is present only in a ghostly or spectral manner.

We speak of *phantom limbs*, the sensation an amputee has that the limb is still present.

So a phantom door would be a sort of ghostly door, but what that might mean is beyond the scope of this site, as we don't engage in literary interpretation here.